# Unity5, C# - When I add a rigidbody, it disables all my sounds in the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had some AI that walked through objects in the scene, therefore I added rigidbodies to them and changed the script - that chases the player - accordingly. The AI now cannot walk through objects with colliders, however now my background music is not working and other sounds, such as, vehicle noise. However, my reload clicks are working.

Zombie Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class ZombieHoardController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
    public Transform target;

    private Animator myAnimator;
    public bool chaseTarget = true;
    public float stoppingDistance = 2.5f;
    public float delayBetweenAttacks = 1.5f;
    private float attackCooldown;

    private float distanceFromTarget;

    public int damage = 1;
    private PlayerHealth playerHealth;

    Rigidbody myRigidBody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        navMeshAgent.stoppingDistance = stoppingDistance;
        attackCooldown = Time.time;

        playerHealth = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(target.position, this.myRigidBody.position) < 15)
        {
            Vector3 direction = target.position - this.myRigidBody.position;
            direction.y = 0;

            this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f);

            ChaseTarget();
        }

        else
        {
            myAnimator.SetBool("isIdle", true);

            //Turn running off
            myAnimator.SetBool("isChasing", false);
            chaseTarget = false;
        }
    }

    void ChaseTarget()
    {
        distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(target.position, myRigidBody.position);

        if (distanceFromTarget >= stoppingDistance)
        {
            chaseTarget = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chaseTarget = false;
            Attack();
        }

        if (chaseTarget)
        {
            navMeshAgent.SetDestination(target.position);
            myAnimator.SetBool("isChasing", true);
        }
        else
        {
            myAnimator.SetBool("isChasing", false);
        }
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        if (Time.time > attackCooldown)
        {
            playerHealth.TakeDamage(damage);

            myAnimator.SetTrigger("Attack");
            attackCooldown = Time.time + delayBetweenAttacks;
        }
    }

}
```

When I change the 'myrigidbody." to transform and remove the rigidbodies, the sounds play again.

Comment: You're not adding Rigidbody anywhere in your code....

Comment: @Programmer What do you mean not adding it, initialising it?

Comment: Your title says *" When I add a rigidbody"* so I am telling you that you are not adding rigidbody from your code.

Comment: @Programmer I am adding it in Unity to the AI, haven't changed any of the settings, then I am setting it up in the script.

Comment: @Jay What happens when you change the 'myrigidbody' to transform but do not remove rigidbody component. I think that should solve the issue.

Comment: @MukeshSaini Yeah the AI stop walking through objects however my audio has been stopped, just the background music, little sound effects still work though.